# Ant Design Table with child rows open by default

Tags: reactjs, antd

How to render a nested ant-design table with child rows open by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `expandable` object's `defaultExpandAllRows` prop in table props. See the
[documentation](https://ant.design/components/table/#expandable) for reference.

```js
const { Table } = antd

const App = () => {

  const columns = [
    {
      title: 'Name',
      dataIndex: 'name',
      key: 'name',
    },
    {
      title: 'Age',
      dataIndex: 'age',
      key: 'age',
    }
  ]
  
  const data = [
    {
      key: 1,
      name: 'Joe Parent',
      age: 60,
      children: [
        {
          key: 11,
          name: 'John Child',
          age: 42,
          children: [
            {
              key: 111,
              name: 'Lea Grandchild',
              age: 23
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    } 
  ]
  return (
    <Table
     columns={columns}
     dataSource={data}
      expandable={{
        defaultExpandAllRows: true
        
      }}     
    />
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App element=">"/>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```css
@import 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/antd/4.15.0/antd.min.css'
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/antd/4.15.0/antd.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Its possible change the `children` name? to `childrenName` ?

Comment: Yes, you just need to update the `dataIndex` prop in the columns array accordingly.